# Powerbi - different gateway name when viewing dataset lineage vs in "manage gateways" section

Tags: powerbi

In powerbi > settings > manage gateways i can see all the on premise gateways.

In one dataset however, if i view the lineage, it shows a gateway, but the name matches nothing in my list of gateways.
This is what i see in the lineage:
[image]

here is what i see in the manage gateways section:
[image]

My question is where is the name coming from in the lineage view?

Comment: Are you sure that Dataset isn't mapped to a gateway that you don't have access to?

Comment: Yes, because if I check the dataset settings >gateway, the correct gateway is selected from the drop-down.

Comment: Did the gateway get renamed?